# How to take random projections in LSH when there are both Numerical and Categorical Data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, dimensionality-reduction, locality-sensitive-hash

**Note : Using LSH for a Nearest Neighbor Query**

Assuming the data set has 5 features (f1,f2,..,f5)
Where the first 2 are Numerical and 3 are categorical. And one or many of these categories maybe something like username or subject which would be quite large to encode.

If we use Mixeducledian Distance as a distace measure and use it in the Hash Function what should be or how do I select the Random Projections for the function ?

Its ok if i have to change the HashFunction.

Sample data

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
89,43,aa,bq,wb
23,67,cd,zd,cs
98,32,aa,wb,cc
10,20,aq,zd,wb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the categorical features into dummy features.
You can check the following options:

- Encoding, like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)
- If you have dataframes, [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) is straightforward

Hope it helps.

Comment: Encoding them might work when the dataSet has fewer categories If that's the case i would have stuck with ANN for hashing. Since the number of categories are very high I'm considering LSH for the nearest neighbor Query.

Comment: maybe elaborate about the categories/data?

Comment: Lets say one or more of them might be something like username or account branch or anything that would be too large to just encode.